# How do I reformat the date from yyyy/MM/dd to dd/MM/yyyy? where in my code can I reformat it?

Tags: c#

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("loaninfo.csv"))
{
    string? s = sr.ReadLine(); // read the heading
                               // display the heading
    if (s != null)
    {
        string[] heading = s.Split(',');
        Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1,15} {2,15} {3,15} {4, 10} {5, 10} {6, 10}",
        heading[0], heading[1], heading[2], heading[3], "Days loan", "Days overdue", "Fine");
        // repeat until end of file
    }
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] detail = s.Split(',');
        dateBorrowed = detail[2];
        dateReturned = detail[3];


        DateTime dateBorrowedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateBorrowed);
        DateTime dateReturnedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateReturned);

        int daysLoan = dateReturnedDateTime.Subtract(dateBorrowedDateTime).Days;
        

        Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1,15} {2,15} {3,15} {4, 10} {5, 10} {6, 10}",
        detail[0], detail[1], detail[2], detail[3], daysLoan, "","");
    }
}
```

I tried adding it after Convert.ToDateTime(dateBorrowed) in line 22 and 23 but it showed an error.Even tried adding it in WriteLine after detail[] but nothing works. Thank you

Comment: You can use the `DateTime.Parse` or `.ParseExact` methods to convert from a `string` to a `DateTime`. If the input might not be valid, use `.TryParse` or `.TryParseExact` instead. You can then call `ToString` on that `DateTime` to output the format you want. If you're calling `Console.WriteLine` or any other method that uses composite formatting, you can include the format specifier there, e.g. `Console.WriteLine("{0:d/MM/yyyy,15}", DateTime.Now)`.

Comment: It should be noted that `"{0:d/MM/yyyy,15}"` in the "Console.WriteLine()" example above is just an alias for [Object.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring).  Which you can override at will.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime.ToString` with the desired format:

```
dateBorrowed = dateBorrowedDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dateReturned = dateReturnedDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's either necessary to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, as i did, or escape the `/` in the format string, otherwise [it gets replaced with your current culture's date-separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator), which might be different. So you could also use:

```
dateReturned = dateReturnedDateTime.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Comment: Or `.ToShortDateString()` https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-6.0 | Or `.ToString("d")` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @RandRandom: I thought op wanted to force that format. With these approaches its not ensured in any culture.